# Combining two partitioned streams into one stream

Tags: azure, streaming, azure-eventhub

I am new to Azure event hub. With the event hub, we receive data from IoT device and the data are partitioned into two streams by assigning partition number "0" and " 1".

The reason why we need two streams is that one is needed for training the "deep learning model" and another one is needed for testing the model we trained with new data coming in from the other side.

This is called "online learning".

However, in the case where we do not have a training model yet, we are not able to test it with the model, so instead of having two streams in this case, I would rather combine two partitioned streams into one so that there is no waste in data. Later once the model is created then we can have two streams back to test and train at the same time.

I could not find any module that enables to combine them in event hub scripts. Any suggestions?

Comment: when do you want to combine the 2 streams? during sending or receiving?

Comment: @IvanYang Hi :) Those are meant to be combined after receiving.

Comment: and it's using python code? and how do you want to combine, like appending the test stream to the training stream after receiving?

Comment: @IvanYang Oh, it seems like you got a solution already. Yes, I would like to append those two queues. As you know, if we do not assign partition's number in producer, it would automatically split into two streams such that one group of odd order another group of even order. I want them to be in the original format before the split.

Comment: If you have not sent these data, then I remember there is a property field you can add when sending the data, and MS suggests that we can use the property to know the sequence of these data.

Comment: @IvanYang so the idea is that rather than literally combining them, we could let one receiver receives data across all partitions and this can be done using "eventprocessorhost"

Comment: This can be used with "eventProcessorHost", if you think the solution is ok, you can take a try, or I can provide the code:).

Comment: @IvanYang Would you mind to share your code here please?

Comment: This can be implemented in different ways to consume messages from Event Hubs directly plus the option to use things like Streaming Analytics which are probably built on top of the two direct ways. The first way is the Event Hub Receiver:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubreceiver?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=azure-dotnet#microsoft_servicebus_messaging_eventhubreceiver, the second which is higher level is the Event Processor Host : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-event-processor-host.

Comment: @BrianLee, do you prefer python code or c# code?

Comment: @IvanYang Oh. Python please, thanks!!

Comment: @BrianLee, can you control the incoming data to event hub? like add properties before it sends to event hub?

Comment: @IvanYang What kind of properties are you referring to? This is not on my end but I can ask my colleague if there's anything that need to be changed.

Comment: @BrianLee, At least I need to 2 properties for each event data, one is "category" with value like "test" or "train", another one is "sequence number" with a dynamic value like 1,2,3 , which can be used to sequence. I can set these properties if I write my code to send data. But for you case(I don't know how the data is sent to eventhub), not sure if you can set these properties.

Comment: @IvanYang I do receive "last_sn" which is for sequence_number and a bunch of dictionaries in JSON format. I think I should be able to set something similar. If you don't mind would you be able to share your "send" code here as well? I greatly appreciate it. You contribute a lot to this field actually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203069/discussion-between-ivan-yang-and-brian-lee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add properties to the data during sending to event hub, then you can try the steps below.

1.We need to set 2 properties for each event data.

**For test data**, we can add the following 2 properties:

**property_name: "category", its velue: "test"**, which is used to determine which kind of data you're receiving, like for test or for train.

**property_name: "seqNum", its value is number**, like 0,1,2,3, which is used to determine the sequence of the data.

And for **train data**, use the steps above, just change category value to "**train**".

I set these properties in c# code, looks like below. You can set it via your own way without c#:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < numMessagesToSend; i++)
        {                
                var message = "555 Message";
                EventData mydata = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));

                //add properties
                mydata.Properties.Add("seqNum", i);
                mydata.Properties.Add("category", "test");
                await eventHubClient.SendAsync(mydata);

         }
```

Then use the following python code to receive the data. Here, I define 2 dicts, one for store test data, another for store train data.

```
import logging
import asyncio
import os
import sys
import signal
import functools

from azure.eventprocessorhost import (
    AbstractEventProcessor,
    AzureStorageCheckpointLeaseManager,
    EventHubConfig,
    EventProcessorHost,
    EPHOptions
)

# define 2 dictionaries, to store test data and train data respectively.
dict_test={}
dict_train={}

class EventProcessor(AbstractEventProcessor):

    def __init__(self, params=None):       
        super().__init__(params)
        self._msg_counter = 0

    async def open_async(self, context):        
        print("Connection established {}".format(context.partition_id))

    async def close_async(self, context, reason):

        print("Connection closed (reason {}, id {}, offset {}, sq_number {})".format(
            reason,
            context.partition_id,
            context.offset,
            context.sequence_number))

    async def process_events_async(self, context, messages):

        for m in messages:
            data = m.body_as_str()
            if m.application_properties is not None:
                mycategory = m.application_properties.get(b'category').decode('utf-8')
                mysequence = str(m.application_properties.get(b'seqNum'))                

                if mycategory == 'test':
                    dict_test[mysequence]=data

                if mycategory == 'train':
                    dict_train[mysequence]=data

                print("Received data: {}".format(data))
        await context.checkpoint_async()

    async def process_error_async(self, context, error):

        print("Event Processor Error {!r}".format(error))


async def wait_and_close(host):

    await asyncio.sleep(60)
    await host.close_async()

try:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    # Storage Account Credentials
    STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME = "xxx"
    STORAGE_KEY = "xxxx"
    LEASE_CONTAINER_NAME = "xxx"
    NAMESPACE = "xxx"
    EVENTHUB = "xxx"
    USER = "RootManageSharedAccessKey"
    KEY = "xxxx"

    # Eventhub config and storage manager 
    eh_config = EventHubConfig(NAMESPACE, EVENTHUB, USER, KEY, consumer_group="$default")
    eh_options = EPHOptions()
    eh_options.release_pump_on_timeout = True
    eh_options.debug_trace = False
    storage_manager = AzureStorageCheckpointLeaseManager(
        STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, STORAGE_KEY, LEASE_CONTAINER_NAME)

    # Event loop and host
    host = EventProcessorHost(
        EventProcessor,
        eh_config,
        storage_manager,
        ep_params=["param1","param2"],
        eph_options=eh_options,
        loop=loop)



    tasks = asyncio.gather(
        host.open_async(),
        wait_and_close(host))
    loop.run_until_complete(tasks)

    print("***this is the data for test***")
    print(dict_test)
    print("***-----------------------***")
    print("***this is the data for train***")
    print(dict_train)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # Canceling pending tasks and stopping the loop
    for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
        task.cancel()
    loop.run_forever()
    tasks.exception()

finally:
    loop.stop()
```

The test result as below:

[image]

The last step, since the test data / train data are stored in dictionaries respectively, and the keys of the dict are the sequence number, you can write your code to operate the dict, rebuilt test data / train data in sequence.