# Receiving messages using Asyncio (Asynchronously) and get the variable as final result

Tags: azure, streaming, python-asyncio, azure-eventhub

In eventhub, I am trying to receive data concurrently by using asyncio module and this was disccused in  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59023823/combining-two-partitioned-streams-into-one-stream).

**The issue that I am addressing here is that when I define a variable under for loop, it is just disappeared when the loop is stopped with loop.stop()**

The code is almost identical to the one linked above.

The class defined is following:

```
global list_
list_ = []

class EventProcessor(AbstractEventProcessor):

    def __init__(self, params=None):       
        super().__init__(params)
        self._msg_counter = 0

    async def open_async(self, context):        
        print("Connection established {}".format(context.partition_id))

    async def close_async(self, context, reason):

        print("Connection closed (reason {}, id {}, offset {}, sq_number {})".format(
            reason,
            context.partition_id,
            context.offset,
            context.sequence_number))

    async def process_events_async(self, context, messages):

         for event_data in messages:
            last_offset = event_data.offset.value
            last_sn = event_data.sequence_number
            data = event_data.body_as_str(encoding= 'UTF-8')
            list_.append(data)
            print("Received data: {}, Num:{}".format(last_sn, len(list_))

            if len(list_) == 10:
               self.loop.close()   ## <- it does not stop at len(list_) == 10
              #self.loop.stop()    ## <- it does stop but the "list_" is dissapeared.  


    async def process_error_async(self, context, error):

        print("Event Processor Error {!r}".format(error))
```

As I commented above, the usage of self.loop.close() and self.loop.stop() did not work in a way that I wanted.

For the next code, it just makes a loop and runs until complete tasks

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# Storage Account Credentials
STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME = "xxx"
STORAGE_KEY = "xxxx"
LEASE_CONTAINER_NAME = "xxx"
NAMESPACE = "xxx"
EVENTHUB = "xxx"
USER = "RootManageSharedAccessKey"
KEY = "xxxx"

# Eventhub config and storage manager 
eh_config = EventHubConfig(NAMESPACE, EVENTHUB, USER, KEY, consumer_group="$default")
eh_options = EPHOptions()
eh_options.release_pump_on_timeout = True
eh_options.debug_trace = False
storage_manager = AzureStorageCheckpointLeaseManager(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, STORAGE_KEY, LEASE_CONTAINER_NAME)

# Event loop and host
host = EventProcessorHost(
    EventProcessor,
    eh_config,
    storage_manager,
    ep_params=["param1","param2"],
    eph_options=eh_options,
    loop=loop)



tasks = asyncio.gather(
    host.open_async(),
    wait_and_close(host))
loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
```

The final variable that I would like to export from is the "list_"

Answer (score -1):

As of now, I cannot find a solution to stop it when the condition is met, but as a workaround, we can control how many event data can be added into list_.

Here is an example:

```
import logging
import asyncio
import os
import sys
import signal
import functools

from azure.eventprocessorhost import (
    AbstractEventProcessor,
    AzureStorageCheckpointLeaseManager,
    EventHubConfig,
    EventProcessorHost,
    EPHOptions
)

global list_
list_ = []

class EventProcessor(AbstractEventProcessor):
    """
        Example Implmentation of AbstractEventProcessor
    """
    def __init__(self, params=None):
        """
        Init Event processor
        """

        super().__init__(params)
        self._msg_counter = 0

    async def open_async(self, context):
        """
        Called by processor host to initialize the event processor.
        """
        print("Connection established {}".format(context.partition_id))

    async def close_async(self, context, reason):
        """
        Called by processor host to indicate that the event processor is being stopped.
        :param context: Information about the partition
        :type context: ~azure.eventprocessorhost.PartitionContext
        """
        print("Connection closed (reason {}, id {}, offset {}, sq_number {})".format(
            reason,
            context.partition_id,
            context.offset,
            context.sequence_number))

    async def process_events_async(self, context, messages):
        """
        Called by the processor host when a batch of events has arrived.
        This is where the real work of the event processor is done.
        :param context: Information about the partition
        :type context: ~azure.eventprocessorhost.PartitionContext
        :param messages: The events to be processed.
        :type messages: list[~azure.eventhub.common.EventData]
        """

        for m in messages:
            data = m.body_as_str()          
            print("Received data: {}".format(data))
            if len(list_) < 10:
                list_.append(data)


    async def process_error_async(self, context, error):
        """
        Called when the underlying client experiences an error while receiving.
        EventProcessorHost will take care of recovering from the error and
        continuing to pump messages,so no action is required from
        :param context: Information about the partition
        :type context: ~azure.eventprocessorhost.PartitionContext
        :param error: The error that occured.
        """
        print("Event Processor Error {!r}".format(error))

async def wait_and_close(host):
    """
    Run EventProcessorHost for 2 minutes then shutdown.
    """
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    await host.close_async()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# Storage Account Credentials
STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME = "xxx"
STORAGE_KEY = "xxx"
LEASE_CONTAINER_NAME = "xxx"
NAMESPACE = "xxxx"
EVENTHUB = "xxx"
USER = "RootManageSharedAccessKey"
KEY = "xxx"

# Eventhub config and storage manager 
eh_config = EventHubConfig(NAMESPACE, EVENTHUB, USER, KEY, consumer_group="$default")
eh_options = EPHOptions()
eh_options.release_pump_on_timeout = True
eh_options.debug_trace = False
storage_manager = AzureStorageCheckpointLeaseManager(
STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, STORAGE_KEY, LEASE_CONTAINER_NAME)

# Event loop and host
host = EventProcessorHost(
    EventProcessor,
    eh_config,
    storage_manager,
    ep_params=["param1","param2"],
    eph_options=eh_options,
    loop=loop)

tasks = asyncio.gather(
    host.open_async(),
    wait_and_close(host))
loop.run_until_complete(tasks)   

print("*the length of list_*")
print(len(list_))
print("***the value from list_ variable***")
print(list_)
```

The result:

[image]